# Why are my actors not being drawn with the correct bounds in LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have been having a hell of a time trying to get this stage thing figured out.  I basically want to draw a background image that fills the entire stage.  The image is 1920x1080.  The problem is that the image is being drawn at half the width and half of the height that it should be.  The application is set to fullscreen and the inside corner of the image is at the center of the screen.  I have tested the dimensions of the camera, the viewport, and the stage.  All are correct.  What am I doing wrong?  By the way, I am using a custom game state manager to handle different screens so I apologize for the seemingly needless extra code.

Application.java

```
public class Application extends ApplicationAdapter {

    public static boolean DEBUG = false;
    public static final String TITLE = "Hexatan";
    public static final int V_WIDTH = 720, V_HEIGHT = 480;
    public static final float SCALE = 2.0f;

    private GameStateManager gsm;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private FitViewport vp;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Stage stage;
    private float w, h;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(true, w / SCALE, h / SCALE);
        vp = new FitViewport(w, h, camera);
        stage = new Stage(vp, batch);
        gsm = new GameStateManager(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        gsm.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        gsm.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        gsm.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gsm.resize((int)(width / SCALE), (int)(height / SCALE));
    }

    public SpriteBatch getBatch() {
        return this.batch;
    }

    public OrthographicCamera getCamera(){
        return this.camera;
    }

    public Stage getStage(){
        return this.stage;
    }
}
```

GameStateManager.java

```
public class GameStateManager {

    private final Application app;
    private Stack<GameState> states;
    public enum State {
        SPLASH, MAINMENU, GAME
    }

    public GameStateManager(final Application app){
        this.app = app;
        this.states = new Stack<GameState>();
        this.setState(State.GAME);
    }

    public Application getApp(){
        return app;
    }

    public void update(float delta){
        states.peek().update(delta);
    }

    public void render(){
        states.peek().render();
    }

    public void dispose(){
        for(GameState gs : states){
            gs.dispose();
        }
        states.clear();
    }

    public void resize(int w, int h){
        states.peek().resize(w, h);
    }

    public void setState(State state){
        if(states.size() >= 1) {
            states.pop().dispose();
        }
        states.push(getState(state));
    }

    public GameState getState(State state){
        return new GameLoop(this);
    }
}
```

GameState.java

```
public abstract class GameState {

    protected GameStateManager gsm;
    protected Application app;

    protected SpriteBatch batch;
    protected OrthographicCamera camera;

    public GameState(GameStateManager gsm){
        this.gsm = gsm;
        this.app = gsm.getApp();
        batch = app.getBatch();
        camera = app.getCamera();

    }

    public void resize(int w, int h){
        camera.setToOrtho(true, w, h);
        camera.update();
    }

    public abstract void update(float delta);
    public abstract void render();
    public abstract void dispose();
}
```

GameLoop.java

```
public class GameLoop extends GameState {

private boolean DEV_MODE = true;
private int WIDTH, HEIGHT;
private float mouseX, mouseY;
private Stage stage;
private Game game;
private Application app;
Texture hexture, water, island, robber, highlight, scoreboard;
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("core/assets/Playbill.fnt"));
BitmapFont devFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("core/assets/Arial.fnt"));

public GameLoop(GameStateManager gsm){
    super(gsm);
    app = gsm.getApp();
    WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    stage = app.getStage();
    System.out.println(stage.getCamera().position.x);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    water = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("core/assets/img/water.png"));
    island = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("core/assets/img/island.png"));
    highlight = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("core/assets/img/highlightVertex.png"));
    scoreboard = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("core/assets/img/scoreboard.png"));

    Image waterImg = new Image(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(water)));
    waterImg.setWidth(WIDTH);
    waterImg.setHeight(HEIGHT);
    stage.addActor(waterImg);

}

@Override
public void render() {
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    app.getStage().act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    app.getStage().draw();
}

@Override
public void update(float delta) {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
@Override
public void resize(int w, int h){
    camera.setToOrtho(true, w, h);
    app.getStage().getViewport().update(w, h, true);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting image position and scale also ?

Comment: You are using Viewport wrong. Need to review the documentation on the Viewport classes.

Comment: @11thdimension I thought that if I didn't set those the defaults would be used, right?  So the default position would be 0,0 which is what I want.

Comment: @Tenfour04 What am I doing wrong with the Viewport?  I can't see any difference between what I'm doing and what the docs show.

Comment: The dimensions you pass to the constructor should be constants, not based on device screen size. Not sure what else. That's a lot of code to go through.

Comment: You also should never be directly setting the size of a camera that is owned by a viewport.